# Convolution operator is normal

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider the convolution operator $$Tf(s)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)h(s-t)\,\,dt,\quad f\in L^2[0,2\pi]$$
where $h:\Bbb R\to \Bbb C$ is a $2\pi$-periodic function, square integrable on $[0,2\pi]$.

**How can we see that $T$ is normal, i.e. $T^*T=TT^*$?**

It ought to be rather easy but I got stuck. Here is what I tried. $T$ is an integral operator with kernel $k(s,t)=h(s-t)$. Then one knows that $T^*$ is the integral operator with kernel $k^*(s,t)=\overline{k(t,s)}=\overline{h(t-s)}$.

Hence, we need to show equality of the following two expressions:

$$T^*Tf(x)=\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)\overline{h(x-s)}h(s-t)\,\,dt\,ds$$

and

$$TT^*f(x)=\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)\overline{h(t-s)}h(x-s)\,\,dt\, ds$$

Comment: Writing this without integrals:  $T*Tf=(f *h)*\overline h = f*(h*\overline h)$. So, all you need is  $h*\overline h = \overline h *h$.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use that the convolution operator is unitarily equivalent to multiplication with the Fourier transform of $h$. It is rather obvious that multiplication operators are normal.